# Topologized by convergence in probability?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory

What is the topology when it is refered to the topology of convergence in probability, or "the space is topologized by convergence in probability"?

Let say you have a space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$, and a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converging in probability to X. Then for any $\epsilon$, $P(\{\omega : |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| > \epsilon \})\rightarrow 0$.

But what does it mean that we equip the space of random variables with the topology of convergence in probability? What are the actual open sets in this topology? All I see is for instance that for any open set around $X$ then there exists an N such that for $n \ge N$ the sequence $X_n$ is in this open set. But this is just an observation, how are the open sets actually constructed, and is the topology unique?

A reference for my question is Protter: Stochastic integration and differential equations. On page 52 he writes: "*We also write $\textbf{L}^0$ for the space of finite-valued random variables topologized by convergence in probability."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach is taking $d(X,Y)=E[|X-Y|\wedge 1]$, where $\wedge$ is for the min: $a\wedge b=\min\{a,b\}$. Then $d:L^0\times L^0\to\mathbb{R}$, up to almost sure equivalence, is a metric and the topology that it generates is convergence in probability. That is, if we denote by $X_n\stackrel{P_*}{\rightarrow} X$ convergence in $d$-metric, and by $X_n\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} X$ as usual probability convergence, then $X_n\stackrel{P_*}{\rightarrow} X$ iff $X_n\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} X$:

- Suppose $X_n\stackrel{P_*}{\rightarrow} X$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since events $\{w\in\Omega\,|\,|X_n(w)-X(w)|\ge\epsilon\}$ and $\{w\in\Omega\,|\,|X_n(w)-X(w)|\wedge 1\ge\epsilon\wedge 1\}$ are equal, then, by Chevyshev, $$P(|X_n-X|\ge\epsilon)=P(|X_n-X|\wedge1\ge\epsilon\wedge1)\le\frac{E[|X_n-X|\wedge1]}{\epsilon\wedge 1}=\frac{d(X_n,X)}{\epsilon\wedge 1}.$$

Doing $n\to\infty$ we get $X_n\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} X$.

- Now suppose $X_n\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} X$. Let $\epsilon<1$. Note that, in general, we can calculate the expectation of a nonnegative random variable as $E[Y]=\int_0^\infty P(Y\ge x)dx$. Thus
  $\begin{multline*}
  d(X_n,X)=\int_0^\infty P(|X_n-X|\wedge 1\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
  =\int_0^1 P(|X_n-X|\wedge 1\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^\infty P(|X_n-X|\wedge 1\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
  =\int_0^1 P(|X_n-X|\wedge 1\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x,
  \end{multline*}$

cause $P(|X_n-X|\wedge 1\ge x)=0$ for $x>1$. Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
&&E[|X_n-X|\wedge1]\nonumber\\
&=&\int_0^\infty P(|X_n-X|\wedge 1\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x\nonumber\\ 
&=&\int_0^1 P(|X_n-X|\wedge 1\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x\nonumber\\
&=&\int_0^\epsilon P(|X_n-X|\wedge 1\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_\epsilon^1 P(|X_n-X|\wedge 1\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x\nonumber\\
&\le&\epsilon+(1-\epsilon)P(|X_n-X|\wedge 1\ge \epsilon)\nonumber\\
&\le&\epsilon+(1-\epsilon)P(|X_n-X|\ge \epsilon)\nonumber\\
\end{eqnarray}\

Now it is easy to conclude.

Comment: I think the two events are not equal, but the first event belongs to the second event.

Comment: It is sufficient to consider $\varepsilon < 1$. The inequality used is the Markov inequality.

Comment: Hi sorry, to me it is not clear still what the open sets are now. Could you maybe write it down explicitely?

Answer (score 5):

If we define
$$ \rho(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}\Big[\frac{|X-Y|}{1+|X-Y|}\Big]$$
then one can show that $\rho$ is a metric on $L^0$ (up to almost sure equivalence), and that $X_n\to X$ with respect to $\rho$ if and only if $X_n\to X$ in probability. So this is one possible approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!